# Cargar Web Form y funciones desde un evento click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

a ver si me podéis ayudar,lo que quiero hacer es cargar un webform (por ejemplo datos.aspx) cuando haga click en cualquiera de los textbox que presento. Lo he intentado con el evento TextChanged pero este evento no se produce cuando hago cambio el texto, sino cuando cambio el texto y pulso enter, aunque tenga puesto AutoPostBack="True". Por otro lado tampoco encuentro la forma de ejecutar una simple función que no devuelva nada, hasta ahora lo he podido hacer con javascript Me.TextBox2.Attributes("onclick") = "funcion()" pero no en asp.net con visual basic. Agradeceria me orienteis